# Link between current profile picture and the original photo in the profile album

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to have a link between the currently used profile picture and the original source in the profile album.

I'm getting the profile picture with:

```
/me/picture?redirect=false
```

Which will return url, width & height but unfortunately no id. (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/profile-picture-source/)

I'm getting all the albums with:

```
/me/albums?fields=id,type
```

Then I'm iterating through all the albums to find the one with the type=='profile' and then retrieve all the photos of this album:

```
/{albumId}/photos?fields=width,height,id,images
```

How can I identify the photo used as the profile picture?
Since we have no id returned from the /me/picture endpoint I don't see a way to make the link between the two objects.

Also, I'm not sure that we can rely on CDN urls to parse them and try to find the profile picture id.

Comment: No, you should not rely on parsing CDN URLs. They do change over time. What do you need the profile image id for? AFAIK it used to be that the first photo in the Profile Pictures album is the current profile picture – not sure if that is still the case, no that you can set profile pictures to be only temporary. Also, if you make an old profile picture the current one again, not sure if it gets pulled to the top of the album’s photos again.

Comment: Exactly, when you use an old profile picture as the current one, it won't be the first in the album list. I need to build a profile page with the profile pictures of the FB user with the current profile picture as the first one of my profile

Comment: Again – what do you need the id for?

Comment: I need to build a profile page with the profile pictures of the FB user. The current FB profile picture **NEEDS** to be the first one of my profile photos.

Comment: Then I’m afraid you can really only compare CDN URLs, and hope the one you get for `/me/picture` and the ones for `/profile-pictures-album-id/photos` are the same. (So requesting them in the same size should be a must.) Or you show the current profile picture at top using `/me/picture`, and ignore the fact that it gets repeated in the list of all album photos.

Comment: The urls returned by both endpoints are not the same but the image filename used in both seems to always match. So Instead of comparing urls, I will parse them and compare filename.